# Managing nuclear waste

Tags: pressure, temperature, density, nuclear-engineering

Suppose you are trying to dispose of used uranium fuel rods. Once they are cooled and contained in zirconium pods, how would one try and send those pods to the earths core?

This is all hypothetical.

I was thinking about dropping it in a volcano, but how can I make it sink?
Since this is hypothetical, I thought about using 'starlite' for heat resistance, and 'glassy carbon' for pressure resistance.

Answer (score 1):

The conventional method of nuclear waste disposal is just fine. Just bury it deep into some geologically inactive rock.

Consider this: If you dig a deep hole into ground in some geologically inactive area, you will find rocks and minerals that have been there for millions of years. If you put your nuclear waste there, there is no reason why it wouldn't stay there for next several million years.

Moreover, read this: http://www.world-nuclear.org/info/nuclear-fuel-cycle/nuclear-wastes/radioactive-waste-management/

You will see, that the actual volume you need to bury is comparatively very small. For 1 GW light water reactor they estimate about $28\,\rm{m^3}$ of processed highly radioactive waste *per year* including disposal canisters. You can fit that inside a 3-meter cube.

Comment: Managing nuclear waste requires the collected efforts of a large number of disciplines and is therefore not easily treated in a single StackExchange site. Airguru’s answer represents one side of the debate. The opposite side will tell you that peat bogs may contain uranium emanating from the surrounding rocks and - if burnt - the ashes’ uranium content may exceed 200 ppm. Some substances in the host rock do therefore move. This leads us to other – perhaps engineered - barriers and their function and yet new disciplines.